# AWS t2.micro instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, amazon-ebs

I have one service running on my t2.micro instance. How can i confirm if there is any bandwidth and storage limit or not.
Attached is that status screen shot of it.[image]

Please guide me on this.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

**Bandwidth**

The only bandwidth limitation in AWS is [related to the **Instance Type**](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ebs-ec2-config.html) of Amazon EC2 instances.

Put simply, smaller instances have less bandwidth than larger instances. You'll see this in the **Launch Instance** screen (right column):

[image: EC2 Launch Instance]

The documentation doesn't specifically say what bandwidth you are given, but you can run some performance tests to determine available throughput.

**Storage**

There are two types of disk storage for Amazon EC2 instances:

- Instance Storage
- Amazon Elastic Block Store (EBS)

[**Instance Storage**](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/InstanceStorage.html) is disk storage that is directly-attached to the instance (or, more accurately, to the host computer running the instance). As you'll see in the *Instance Storage* column in the above picture, not all EC2 instances have Instance Storage -- some of them just say "EBS only", meaning that it is not available.

For instance types that provide Instance Storage, the size is fixed and is again based on the [Instance Type](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/instance-types/).

The most important thing to know about Instance Storage is that **it is lost when an instance is stopped/terminated**. This is because the virtual machine is deleted, which gives back the CPU, RAM and Instance Storage. Thus, it is only useful for **temporary files, virtual memory swap files and local cache**. Do *not* store the only copy of important data on Instance Storage.

[**Amazon EBS**](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/AmazonEBS.html) is network-attached storage. Data is **retained** when instances are stopped. When they are later started, the disks are exactly the same as when the instance was turned off. When an instance is Terminated, the EBS volume can optionally be kept or deleted.

EBS volumes have the advantage that you can configure a disk of any size up to 16TB and there are various different types of volumes to trade-off cost/performance.

**Bottom line:** Your `t2.micro` instance has no Instance Storage. It has EBS volumes that you have attached (at whatever size you configured). It has *Low to Moderate* network bandwidth.